# Custom NSWindow content margin causes mess up with autoresizing mask

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nswindow, popover

I'm currently using the method shown in [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html) Cocoa with Love article to create a custom NSWindow subclass. As in the example, I needed to have a roughly 10px margin around the content of the window in order to draw an arrow (I'm creating a popover style window). I had to have the margin around the entire window instead of just the side with the arrow on it because I wanted to be able to change the arrow position without having to reposition the content.

To summarize, the method I'm using to do this is (relevant code is at the bottom):

- Override the `contentRectForFrameRect:` and `frameRectForContentRect:styleMask:` methods of NSWindow to add the padding around the content:
- Sets the custom drawn frame view of the window as the `contentView` and then overrides the setter and getter for the `contentView` so that the view that is passed in is added as a **subview** of the frame view.

The problem is that the autoresizing masks of views **inside** the actual content view of the window are completely messed up. Here is how I'm setting up the content in interface builder:

[image: Layout]

Here's how the autoresizing mask of the table view scroll view is set up:

[image: Table View Autoresizing]

And here's how the text label's autoresizing mask is set:

[image: Label Autoresizing]

And here's what the result looks like in-app:

[image: Actual result]

**Relevant code (derived from the aforementioned article)**

```
#define CONTENT_MARGIN 10.0

- (NSRect)contentRectForFrameRect:(NSRect)windowFrame
{
    windowFrame.origin = NSZeroPoint;
    return NSInsetRect(windowFrame, CONTENT_MARGIN, ICONTENT_MARGIN);
}

- (NSRect)frameRectForContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
{
    return NSInsetRect(contentRect, -CONTENT_MARGINT, -CONTENT_MARGIN);
}

+ (NSRect)frameRectForContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect
                        styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle
{
    return NSInsetRect(contentRect, -CONTENT_MARGIN, -CONTENT_MARGIN);
}


- (NSView*)contentView
{
    return _popoverContentView;
}

- (void)setContentView:(NSView *)aView
{
    if ([_popoverContentView isEqualTo:aView]) { return; }
    NSRect bounds = [self frame];
    bounds.origin = NSZeroPoint;
    SearchPopoverWindowFrame *frameView = [super contentView];
    if (!frameView) {
        frameView = [[[SearchPopoverWindowFrame alloc] initWithFrame:bounds] autorelease];
        [super setContentView:frameView];
    }
    if (_popoverContentView) {
        [_popoverContentView removeFromSuperview];
    }
    _popoverContentView = aView;
    [_popoverContentView setFrame:[self contentRectForFrameRect:bounds]];
    [_popoverContentView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];
    [frameView addSubview:_popoverContentView];
}
```

I thought that maybe the popover content was going over the margins somehow, so I drew a border around the content view, but no, everything is as should be. The only issue is that the autoresizing masks of the label and table view inside the content view do not work as they should. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: If anyone's interested, I've open-sourced the complete code for this popover window/controller on github as [INPopoverController](https://github.com/indragiek/INPopoverController). Includes a sample project in case you want to try and reproduce the issue.**

Comment: Xcode 4 is currently under NDA. Are you allowed to show screenshots to us?

Comment: I've removed/replaced the parts that show Xcode 4, but I'm sure everyone knows what it looks like by now.

Comment: Your table view's scroll view should have the strut on the bottom edge connected in the autoresize inspector.

Comment: You have checked out Matt Gemmell's excellent `MAAttachedWindow`?  http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass

Answer (score 1):

```
-( void )scaleWindowForHeight:( float )height
{
    if (height > 22)
    {
        NSWindow* window = [self window];
        NSRect old_window_frame = [window frame];
        NSRect old_content_rect = [window contentRectForFrameRect: old_window_frame];
        NSSize new_content_size = NSMakeSize( old_window_frame.size.width, height );
        // need to move window by Y-axis because NSWindow origin point is at lower side:
        NSRect new_content_rect = NSMakeRect( NSMinX( old_content_rect ), NSMaxY( old_content_rect ) - new_content_size.height, new_content_size.width, new_content_size.height );
        NSRect new_window_frame = [window frameRectForContentRect: new_content_rect];
        [window setFrame: new_window_frame  display:YES  animate: [window isVisible] ];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"window size too small");
}
```